# How to create minimal web server example with a dropdown menu?

Tags: esp8266

I want to create a three-item menu: Verizon, T-Mobile, AT&T. Since the example uses LEDs, I'll do the same--except with a dropdown menu to select among the three.

I'm trying to combine these two examples:

1. https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server
2. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select

Except with phone carriers instead of cars:

[image]

I'm struggling on the polyglot part of the programming, combining the HTML and Arduino program in the middle:

```cpp
        // Web Page Heading
        client.println("<form action='/action_page.php'>");
        client.println("  <select id='providor' name='providor'>");
        client.println("    <option value='verizon'>Verizon</option>");
        client.println("    <option value='tmobile'>T-Mobile</option>");
        client.println("    <option value='atnt'>AT&T</option>");
        client.println("  </select>");
        client.println("  <input type='submit'>");
        client.println("</form>");
        
        if (providor==verizon)
          client.println("<p>Provider Selected: Verizon</p>");
        else if (providor==tmobile)
          client.println("<p>Provider Selected: T-Mobile</p>");
        else if (providor==atnt)
          client.println("<p>Provider Selected: AT&T</p>");
```

Here is the rest of the program:

```cpp
/*

Based from 
https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server

HTML tool
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select
*/

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

// Replace with your network credentials
const char* ssid     = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SSID";
const char* password = "REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_PASSWORD";

// Set web server port number to 80
WiFiServer server(80);

// Variable to store the HTTP request
String header;

// Auxiliar variables to store the current output state
//String output5State = "off";
//String output4State = "off";

// Assign output variables to GPIO pins
const int output5 = 14;    // D5 verizon  
const int output6 = 12;    // D6 tmobile
const int output7 = 13;    // D7 atnt

// Current time
unsigned long currentTime = millis();
// Previous time
unsigned long previousTime = 0; 
// Define timeout time in milliseconds (example: 2000ms = 2s)
const long timeoutTime = 2000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  // Initialize the output variables as outputs
  pinMode(output5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(output7, OUTPUT);  
  // Set outputs to LOW
  digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(output7, LOW);

  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  // Print local IP address and start web server
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected.");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  server.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  WiFiClient client = server.available();   // Listen for incoming clients

  if (client) {                             // If a new client connects,
    Serial.println("New Client.");          // print a message out in the serial port
    String currentLine = "";                // make a String to hold incoming data from the client
    currentTime = millis();
    previousTime = currentTime;
    while (client.connected() && currentTime - previousTime <= timeoutTime) { // loop while the client's connected
      currentTime = millis();         
      if (client.available()) {             // if there's bytes to read from the client,
        char c = client.read();             // read a byte, then
        Serial.write(c);                    // print it out the serial monitor
        header += c;
        if (c == '\n') {                    // if the byte is a newline character
          // if the current line is blank, you got two newline characters in a row.
          // that's the end of the client HTTP request, so send a response:
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            // HTTP headers always start with a response code (e.g. HTTP/1.1 200 OK)
            // and a content-type so the client knows what's coming, then a blank line:
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println("Connection: close");
            client.println();


            
            // turns the GPIOs on and off
            if (header.indexOf("GET /5/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D5 on");
              output5State = "on";
              digitalWrite(output5, HIGH);
            }
            else if (header.indexOf("GET /5/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D5 off");
              output5State = "off";
              digitalWrite(output5, LOW);
            }
            else if (header.indexOf("GET /6/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D6 on");
              output4State = "on";
              digitalWrite(output6, HIGH);
            } 
            else if (header.indexOf("GET /6/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D6 off");
              output4State = "off";
              digitalWrite(output6, LOW);
            }
            else if (header.indexOf("GET /7/on") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D7 on");
              output4State = "on";
              digitalWrite(output7, HIGH);
            } 
            else if (header.indexOf("GET /7/off") >= 0) 
            {
              Serial.println("D7 off");
              output4State = "off";
              digitalWrite(output7, LOW);
            }
            // Display the HTML web page
            client.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html>");
            client.println("<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">");
            client.println("<link rel=\"icon\" href=\"data:,\">");
            // CSS to style the on/off buttons 
            // Feel free to change the background-color and font-size attributes to fit your preferences
            client.println("<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}");
            client.println(".button { background-color: #195B6A; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 40px;");
            client.println("text-decoration: none; font-size: 30px; margin: 2px; cursor: pointer;}");
            client.println(".button2 {background-color: #77878A;}</style></head>");

            // HERE
            // ↓
            // ↓
            // ↓
            // ↓         
              
            // Web Page Heading
            client.println("<form action='/action_page.php'>");
            client.println("  <select id='provider' name='providor'>");
            client.println("    <option value='verizon'>Verizon</option>");
            client.println("    <option value='tmobile'>T-Mobile</option>");
            client.println("    <option value='atnt'>AT&T</option>");
            client.println("  </select>");
            client.println("  <input type='submit'>");
            client.println("</form>");
            
            if (providor==verizon)
              client.println("<p>Provider Selected: Verizon</p>");
            else if (providor==tmobile)
              client.println("<p>Provider Selected: T-Mobile</p>");
            else if (providor==atnt)
              client.println("<p>Provider Selected: AT&T</p>");    
                
            // ↑
            // ↑
            // ↑
            // ↑
            
            client.println("</body></html>");
            
            // The HTTP response ends with another blank line
            client.println();
            // Break out of the while loop
            break;
          } else { // if you got a newline, then clear currentLine
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {  // if you got anything else but a carriage return character,
          currentLine += c;      // add it to the end of the currentLine
        }
      }
    }
    // Clear the header variable
    header = "";
    // Close the connection
    client.stop();
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Any suggestions or solutions on how to change or the correct code?

Comment: what do you expect the drop down menu to do?

Comment: Change a "provider" variable to whichever is selected. And in this case, turn on the LED corresponding to it (one of three LEDs should be on).

Comment: put the HTML code for the drop down menu right after the second button

Comment: I use `<script>document.getElementById('providor').selectedIndex = 'tmobile';</script>`

Comment: Look at the code in your post. It is syntax-highlighted, i.e. color-coded according to the grammar of the C++ language. Don't you see something weird with the colors around “HERE”? That's the syntax-highlighter showing you your syntax error.

Comment: And, further up in the first code block. Your quotes are not matching, all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

First thing: be careful with matching your quotes. Every string literal
should be written as `"bla, bla, bla"`, with no unescaped double-quotes
in between. Do use the syntax highlighting: it is here precisely for
helping you spot this kind of trivial programming mistakes. Also, for
writing very long constant strings, use the C++ “raw string literal”
feature: it just makes this easier.

Second thing, you should understand how a form submission works at the
HTTP level. You should be able to find the info on the Web but, to make
it short, when the user clicks on your form, the browser will send a
request looking like

```
GET /action_page.php?providor=verizon HTTP/1.1
Some-Header-Name: some header value
Other-Header-Name: other header value
...
```

You should parse this to find the actual provider between the `'='`
character and the following space. Also, get rid of `action_page.php`,
it is useless here.

Then a few random remarks:

- Do not write “providor”: the correct spelling is “provider” (although
  you may prefer “carrier” in this context).
- Within an HTML document, the ampersand should be written `&amp;`.
- The HTML page needs a `<title>` element to be valid.
- Remove the whole section of the code titled “turns the GPIOs on and
  off”: it does not make sense in your context.

Now, to illustrate these points, here is how I would code parsing the
request:

```cpp
// Find the provider in the URL.
String provider;
const String provider_before = "GET /?provider=";
int request_begin = header.indexOf(provider_before);
if (request_begin < 0) {
    provider = "unknown";
} else {
    int provider_begin = request_begin + provider_before.length();
    int provider_end = header.indexOf(' ', provider_begin);
    provider = header.substring(provider_begin, provider_end);
}
```

And here is how I would send the page to the client:

```cpp
// At the beginning of the sketch (in global context).
const char page_before_provider[] = R"rawstr(<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Phone carrier selection</title>
[...]
<p>Provider Selected: )rawstr";
const char page_after_provider[] = "</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n";

// At the place where the page has to be sent.
client.print(page_before_provider);
if (provider == "verizon")
    client.print("Verizon");
else if (provider == "tmobile")
    client.print("T-Mobile");
else if (provider == "atnt")
    client.print("AT&amp;T");
else
    client.print(provider);
client.print(page_after_provider);
```

Comment: For the global const char stuff, I am confused. Is that a function I should create? Tried putting some of that in, but pretty confused: https://github.com/adamaero/WebServer/blob/main/polyglot/ESP8266dropDownMenu/ESP8266dropDownMenu.ino

Comment: @adamaero: No, not in a function. “Global context” means outside any function. It's a constant declaration, just like `ssid`, to put at the beginning of the program. PS: do not worry about this until after you fix the first, most important issue: **get your quotes matched**.

Comment: Quotes were matched.

Comment: Since all the current answers are not clear to me, I'll try to come up with my own with `const char page_before_provider[] = R"rawstr(<!DOCTYPE html>

)rawstr";`

Comment: @adamaero: 1. Do you believe quotes are matches in `client.println("<p>carrier Selected: T-Mobile" < / p > ");`? 2. If something is not clear in this answer, please tell what exactly you do not understand, so I can elaborate on that specific point.

Comment: Ok, now the quotes are matched... in the pseudo code that doesn't do anything to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the syntax errors (you aren't matching double quotes in multiple places) web pages don't work like that.

To do something like your form you:

1. Send the form, more-or-less like you have.
2. > ```
   >    if (providor==verizon)
   >        client.println("<p>Providor Selected: Verizon</p>");
   > ```

   You can't test the providor (provider?) right there. Do you mean `if (providor=="verizon")`?
3. The form has to be sent to the client, the user has to fill it in, and send it back. Thus you can't test for what they filled in a line or so under sending the form.

So, testing for what they entered is a subsequent step. It's a little hard to explain without taking dozens of paragraphs. I suggest reading up on how web forms work.

---

Here's an analogy:

Say you want to write to a company and apply for a job. You fill in a form and send it off. You do not, a moment later, check to see if you got the job. The form has to go to the company. Someone has to process it. Then they make a reply. The reply might say "in reference to your job application of 11 September 2023 you were/were not successful."

It's like that with HTML. The form, which the user fills in, is the initial step. Then the user fills it in. That might be an hour later. Then they press Send and the reply comes back to you. *That's* when you process the reply.